# Replace Solid Color with image Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I use this code to create rectangle with solid color on background

```py
def create_image(self):
    image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
        os.path.join('assets', 'ship11.png')), (ship_width, ship_height))
    self.rectangle = pygame.Surface((ship_height, ship_width), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    self.rectangle.fill(pygame.Color('dodgerblue'))
```

how I can use picture that I load in first line in this function in rectangle that I created

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.rectangle` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). Use the [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method to draw a source *Surface* onto a *Surface* object:

```py
self.rectangle.blit(image, (0, 0))
```

---

Function `create_image`:

```py
def create_image(self):
    image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
        os.path.join('assets', 'ship11.png')), (ship_width, ship_height))
        
    self.rectangle = pygame.Surface((ship_width, ship_height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.rectangle.fill(pygame.Color('dodgerblue'))

    self.rectangle.blit(image, (0, 0))
```